# Exclude all files but two

Tags: gulp

I'm feeding `gulp.src()`. I have a `bin` directory where I want to exclude all files except *two*:

```
bin/
    keep-me.bat
    keep-me-too.bat
    ...
```

I've found the way to exclude all files but *one*:

```
gulp.src([
    path.normalize(dirExport + '/..') + '/**',
    '!' + dirExport + '/bin/!(keep-me.bat)'
], {
    dot: true
})
```

... but I'm totally unable to extend this. Whatever I try either includes or excludes the entire directory, e.g.:

```
// Not working
'!' + dirExport + '/bin/!(keep-me.bat)',
'!' + dirExport + '/bin/!(keep-me-too.bat)'
```

How can I whitelist a second file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify additional patterns in `!()` by separating them with `|`. From [the `glob` docs](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#glob-primer):

> `!(pattern|pattern|pattern)` Matches anything that does not match any of the patterns provided.

So in your case:

```
gulp.src([
    path.normalize(dirExport + '/..') + '/**',
    '!' + dirExport + '/bin/!(keep-me.bat|keep-me-too.bat)'
], {
    dot: true
})
```